# Evaluating one way repeated measures anova for significance of a time series

Tags: anova, spss, repeated-measures

I have an experiment with 6 groups (Control and 5 groups for testing) and measure a Parameter (A) for 4 times. Now I want to know at which time point each of the 5 groups start to significantly behave different from the control. 
So I did a one way repeated measures ANOVA for every group combination (Control and group 1, Control and group 2... Control and group 5) for 3 time point combinations (time 1-2, time 1-3 and time 1-4) in SPSS. In total 12 analyses (3 time point combinations * 4 group combinations). 
Now I am not sure how to evaluate the Output. I believe that the Time*Group output is the important one, as I am interested in the change of the parameter over the time - Is that the right approach?

Comment: Is this really repeat measures? If so, what is being repeated on the subjects?

Comment: The same parameter was measured 4 times for each subject. However, the different groups had different treatments.